# Why does dividing a double by zero throws no exception, while dividing a int does?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, int, double

When we divide a `double` by zero it doesn't throw any exception but successfully map to the infinity. But not in the case of `int`.

Despite the fact that both `int` and `double` have got an upper limit to the value that they can hold, like max

```
double = 1.7976931348623157E+308; //not infinity
```

why the `int` is not implemented in the same way?

Please read my question as this--> On what ground this behaviour was built into double but not into int. What was the rational for doing so? even excel also gives the same result as double weather its an int or decimal, but why not the int in c#?

**Edit** all of you are saying that to be compliant with the established industry standard it is so.. i want to know for what reason they set that standard.. **there must be a reason otherwise it will be a dictatorship**

Comment: Also see this article from Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/15/as-timeless-as-infinity.aspx and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609698/inconsistency-in-divide-by-zero-behavior-between-different-value-types)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609698/inconsistency-in-divide-by-zero-behavior-between-different-value-types) is a good answer. And you should first use search and only then ask a new question.

Comment: check this link- http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html#exceptions

Comment: @user2294729, because thats how it was defined, Read the article from Eric Lippert, it has that particular answer. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/15/as-timeless-as-infinity.aspx

Comment: @habib i already went thru it.. it says that to be compliant with the established industry standard  they did so.. i want to know for what reason they set that standard.. there must be a reason otherwise it will be a dictatorship.