# 0.0/0.0 in C# won't throw "Attempted to divide by zero."?

Tags: c#, .net, double

I've seen this finance calculation code at my friend's computer :

```
double Total = ...
double Paid = ...
double Wating_For_Details = ...
double Decuctibles = ...
double Rejected = ...
```

Well , the moment I saw this , I told him that `double` is represented at `base 2` and can *NOT* represent finance calculation. use `decimal` instead.

great.

But the moment I change it to double Ive encountered :

`Attempted to divide by zero.`

HUH ?

Apparently - using `double` , when dividing with `0.0` it does **NOT** throws exception :

[image]

But returns `NAN`.

While my code  (using `decimal`) does  throw exception ( when `Total` is `zero`)

And so I ask :

I checked `0.0==0` and it returns true. so why I'm not getting exception but `NAN`? I know thats how it should be but where is the common sence of not throwing exception when dividing double by zero ?

Comment: "I checked `0.0==0`" - what do you think that actually checked? The operands on both sides are of unequal types, but an implicit conversion for `int` to `double` exists - so what you actually checked was that `0.0==0.0`.

Comment: Also, your question is kind of posed as if throwing an exception is *obviously* the correct thing to do in this situation - there are many trade offs in the world of computing, and often no single "correct" way to do things.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609698/inconsistency-in-divide-by-zero-behavior-between-different-value-types (even though not exactly duplicate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx

> A method or operator returns NaN when the result of an operation is undefined. For example, the result of dividing zero by zero is NaN, as the following example shows.
>   (...)
>   In addition, a method call with a NaN value or an operation on a NaN value returns NaN, as the following example shows.

The following code example illustrates the use of NaN:

```
  Double zero = 0;

  // This condition will return false. 
  if ((0 / zero) == Double.NaN) 
     Console.WriteLine("0 / 0 can be tested with Double.NaN.");
  else 
     Console.WriteLine("0 / 0 cannot be tested with Double.NaN; use Double.IsNaN() instead.");
```

Comment: because NaN == NaN is always false. its in the floating points operations specs

Answer (score 16):

> Unlike operations with integral types, which throw exceptions in cases
>   of overflow or illegal operations such as division by zero, operations
>   with floating-point values do not throw exceptions. Instead, in
>   exceptional situations, the result of a floating-point operation is
>   zero, positive infinity, negative infinity, or not a number (NaN):

[From `Double` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

There is some special behaviour of double when dividing by Zero (0.0):

```
d/0.0 => Double.NaN if d==0.0
d/0.0 => Double.PositiveInfinity if d>0.0
d/0.0 => Double.NegativeInfinity if d<0.0
```

DivideByZeroException is only thrown for Integer (which Decimal is like!)

Answer (score 1):

That is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx):

> A method or operator returns NaN when the result of an operation is undefined. For example, the result of dividing zero by zero is NaN.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28VS.80%29.aspx

> Floating-point arithmetic overflow or division by zero never throws an
>   exception, because floating-point types are based on IEEE 754 and so
>   have provisions for representing infinity and NaN (Not a Number).

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609698/inconsistency-in-divide-by-zero-behavior-between-different-value-types) provides some good background