# C# DivideByZeroException won't execute

Tags: c#, exception

I have written the code below. And I want the output to be :Error!Division by zero.. 
But my output is: infinity.
What's the problem with this code?

//This is the class:

```cs
 public class Exc    
 {
    private double number1;
    private double number2;
    public double result;

    public Exc(double n1,double n2)
    {
        this.number1 = n1;
        this.number2 = n2;
    }

    public void Div(double number1, double number2)
    {

        try
        {
            result = number1 / number2;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error! Division by zero.{0}",e);

        }

    }
}
```

//This is my program:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number:");
    double n1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number:");
    double n2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Exc obj = new Exc(n1, n2);
    obj.Div(n1,n2);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What inputs are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistency in divide-by-zero behavior between different value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609698/inconsistency-in-divide-by-zero-behavior-between-different-value-types)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473074/0-0-0-0-in-c-sharp-wont-throw-attempted-to-divide-by-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Arithmetic operations with the float and double types never throw an exception**. The result of arithmetic operations with those types can be one of special values that represent infinity and not-a-number:

```
double a = 1.0 / 0.0;
Console.WriteLine(a);                    // output: Infinity
Console.WriteLine(double.IsInfinity(a)); // output: True
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#floating-point-arithmetic-overflow)

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now :)

Answer (score 2):

You are going to get divide by zero error only in case of integer input in c#. For double the desired output is infinity. You should put a check for `Double.IsInfinity` if you want to know if it is divided by zero.

Comment: Understood.Thank you!