# Why is a field with a value of 0 not the same as 0 in this formula?

Tags: reporting-services

We've got a report calculating margin which is pretty simple. I understand that there is no short circuiting of an IIF in SSRS. This question is focused on why there is a behavior difference between using field values in a formula, and direct values.

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Sales.Value) = 0, "N/A", 1 - SUM(Fields!Cost.Value) / SUM(Fields!Sales.Value))
```

This formula results in `#error` when `Sales.Value = 0`. However, if I change the formula to the following:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!Sales.Value) = 0, "N/A", 1 - 1 / 0)
```

This results in `"N/A"` like it's supposed to. So `1 - / 0` = `-infinity`, but dividing by a field whose value is 0 results in an error.

Why is the behavior different here?

EDIT: I'll clarify this a bit. Ignoring the IIF aspect of this, if I do:

```
= 1 - 1 / 0
```

I get `-infinity`. If I do (where Sales.Value = 0):

```
= 1 -1 / Fields!Sales.Value
```

I get `#error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [VB documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx), the `Double` data type is the only data type that does not throw the `DivideByZeroException`.  But since you've clearly used two `Int`'s, something else is going on here.

After some searching I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609893/1657324) to a related but different divide-by-zero question, which has a great explanation:

> VB.NET does things a little bit differently; integer division automatically results in a floating point value using the `/` operator. This is to allow developers to write, e.g., the expression `1 / 2`, and have it evaluate to `0.5`, which some would consider intuitive

TL;DR `Fields!Sales.Value` is likely interpreted as a `Decimal` resulting in the divide-by-zero `#error`, while the `1 / 0` example results in a data type of `Double` and displays `infinity`.

Comment: That's as good an explanation as any.  See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/15/as-timeless-as-infinity.aspx