# Why do decimals give a compile time error on division by zero?

Tags: c#

As a follow up from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40907417/why-is-infinity-8), I noticed odd behaviour (with the console) when dividing by zero. I found that the following two statements compile fine:

```
Console.WriteLine(1d / 0d);
Console.WriteLine(1f / 0f);
```

Whereas these two give a compile time error:

```
Console.WriteLine(1 / 0);
Console.WriteLine(1m / 0m);
```

Of

> Division by constant zero

Why is there this difference in behaviour?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel My question is about compile time errors but I assume the reason is the same as the run time error, thanks

Comment: This questions are correlated but it is not a true duplicate : emphasis on compile time error. The other was "why double allow division by 0"

Comment: @Guillaume Although the duplicate answers the question and covers compile and run time errors/exceptions in I, so I believe it is still a dupe

Comment: The behavior is different between compile time and run time evaluation. This question is also about the compiler being unable to produce IL from an expression that has a defined behavior (DivideByZeroException) when evaluted at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Division by 0 is allowed for float and double types. It returns infinity.

For Int32 and Decimal, it is not allowed, it raises an exception.
The compiler doesn't allow division by 0 on constant values because it leads to undefined behavior.

```
public class MyConsts {
public const int i = 1/0; // Constant, compile time evaluation
}

...

Console.WriteLine(MyConsts.i); // What would you expect ?
```

The compiler is unable to compute a proper value for your constant expression. Keep in mind that the value is compiled and not evaluated at runtime so it's not possible to raise an exception.

Comment: Which is exactly what I stated in my question, the question is why

Comment: It is by design. The way different numeric types are implemented... different types, different features.
Why the downvote ?

Comment: I added some details about why it's not possible to evaluate a constant (compile time) division by 0.