# NumberFormatInfo setup

Tags: c#

On two different PCs, for the same executable, I have two different values for

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol
```

I have "∞" vs "Infinity". The two culture are supposed to be identical (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name is "en-US" for both).

If it matters : One PC is running on Windows 10,the other on Windows 7. .Net framework versions installed are 2/3/3.5/4 on both with some variation on the exact version. (4.7.02558 vs 4.6.01055).

1. What can create the NumberFormat being different for a same culture ?
2. Any way to override this discrepency at the PC level ?

Comment: Yes, this changed in Win10.  Find a workaround in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41322533/17034).

Comment: If you require stable culture settings (e.g. for data exchange purposes) you should consider the InvariantCulture which like its name implies will never change.