# Circle's circularity value shows infinity error

Tags: c#, .net, math, aforge

I have a function which calculates the circularity of a circle. if the result is 1.00, the circle is perfectly circular, anything below 1.00 means that the circle is imperfect. It works well except for a small problem, sometimes it shows the value as infinity, im unable to find a reason. I'm using float to calculate it, tried double as well, but the same thing happens.

Here is the code :

```
 for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
 {
     List<IntPoint> edgePoints = bc.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);

     List<IntPoint> hull = hullFinder.FindHull(edgePoints);
     double perimeter = 0.0;
     for (int j = 0; j < hull.Count - 1; j++)
     {
         perimeter += hull[j].DistanceTo(hull[j + 1]);
     }
     perimeter += hull[hull.Count - 1].DistanceTo(hull[0]);

     float circularity = (float)((4 * Math.PI * blob.Area) / (Math.Pow(perimeter, 2)));
     double circround = Math.Round(circularity, 3);
     lblcircle.Text = circround.ToString();
}
```

While stepping through the code, we first see that Perimeter is 0, but circularity is shown:
[image]

Then when I step into the third debug line, the perimeter becomes 0 and the result is infinity:
[image]

Comment: What is `permiter` and `blob.Area` in the error-case? You should be able to inspect their values while debugging.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that we can make an educated guess: floating point arithmetic. I guess you have an issue regarding rounding errors somewhere in the formulas. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609698/982149 I guess perimeter result to zero in some cases. Which for non-static values results in Infinity when devided by for floating point types.

Comment: On a side notde, you should stick with double. You wont need any casting and there is no real benefit of using float.

Comment: It seems you could have issues with blobs that have very small perimeters. Can you confirm if thats the case?

Comment: Well, if `perimeter`is zero, what do you expect `Math.Pow(perimeter, 2)` to return different than zero? Of course this will cause a division by zero making `circularity` to be infinite.

Comment: Hi HimBromBeere, please check the image link attached to my question.

Comment: You shouldn´t trust too much on the debug-view. Obviously `perimeter` is zero, which causes the problem. Maybe debugger isn´t able to calculate the value appropriately for any reason. The important point is that `circularity` is infinite at the moment you print it to the output, which is absolutely what I would expect when seeing your code.

Comment: When I write `float circularity = (float)((4 * Math.PI * 1.0) / (Math.Pow(0.0, 2)));` I immediately get `infinte` for `circularity`, even in the debugger.

Comment: One more thing, when i calculate the circularity of normal circles the function processes just once and exits the debugger, but in the case of the circle where I get infinity, the function is run 5 times with different results and then finally exits the debugger with the infinity result. Strange.!!

Comment: On the first image you obviously have the value for `circularity` from a *previous* run. What does debuggr show you when you execute the line that is yellow on first image? I suppose `infinity` as well.

Comment: The image if for the first image itself, but the circularity value shown comes after third iteration of the function. For some reason, the image which shows infinity error makes the function run 5 times even though in the for loop the blob length is 1.